# Used git merge --continue instead of git rebase --continue

Tags: git, github

On github, I see commits from master branch on my branch after `rebase`, when I want to see only the difference, as usual. I remember that probably I used `git merge --continue` instead of `git rebase --continue` during resolving conflicts. Is it possible that this is the problem?

Comment: I mean... Is this error the reason of the problem?

Comment: Do you mean that when you do `git log` on your `feature` branch, you also see commits which are from `master` as well? So, you only want to see commits from your `feature` branch?

Comment: @mnestorov I mean, that I see commits from master together with commits from my feature branch, and not firstly commits from master and then my commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: `git merge --continue` first checks that there is a suspended merge to finish.<sup>1</sup>  If there is one, it literally just runs `git commit`, at the moment.<sup>2</sup>  If not, it says that there is no merge to finish and does nothing.

Note that what `git rebase` really does is to *copy* some set of existing commits to new-and-improved versions of those commits.  The copying process is pretty similar to running a series of `git cherry-pick` commands.  Depending on how you invoke `git rebase`, you could be telling it to copy commits that are also visible when using the name `master` to find commits.  There is not enough information in your question to tell whether this is the case.

---

<sup>1</sup>This can only result from:

- running `git merge --no-commit`, or
- running a `git merge` that produces conflicts.

A rebase (or cherry-pick or revert) that produces conflicts does not count as a suspended merge, even though it does use Git's merge machinery.

<sup>2</sup>A future version of `git merge --continue` might invoke the same *code* as `git commit` without running an actual separate `git commit` command, but this would have the same effect.